# what is the meaning of " += ( s, e )" in the code?

Tags: c#

What is exactly the `+= ( s, e )` in the code?

example:

`this.currentOperation.Completed += ( s, e ) => this.CurrentOperationChanged();`

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more code? += is the addition assignment operator. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx

Comment: i know that the line i added is to call the CurrentOperationChanged method in case the this.currentOperation.Completed been called. but why do i need the 's and e ' ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is the way to attach an event handler using Lambda expression.

For example:

```
button.Click += new EventHandler(delegate (Object s, EventArgs e) {
            //some code
        });
```

Can be rewritten using lambda as follows:

```
button.Click += (s,e) => {
            //some code
        };
```

One thing to note here. It is not necessary to write 's' and 'e'. You can use any two letters, e.g.

```
button.Click += (o,r) => {};
```

The first parameter would represent the object that fired the event and the second would hold data that can be used in the eventhandler.

Answer (score 6):

This codes adds an event listener in form of a Lambda expression. `s` stands for **sender** and `e` are the **EventArgs**. Lambda for

```
private void Listener(object s, EventArgs e) {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an assignment of a delegate instance (the start of a lambda expression) to an event invocation list. The `s, e` represents the `sender` and `EventArgs` parameters of the event delegate type.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx for more info.

Answer (score 4):

It is a shorthand for an event handler. 
s --> object sender and
e --> some type of EventArgs.

It can also be rewrriten as:

```
public void HandlerFunction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.loaded = true;
}
```